# What is the best way to finance medical screenings for a non-resident alien?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, healthcare, medical-bill, medical-tourism

My dad is coming to visit me from a country with a very poor medical system. The kind of system where senior citizens don't get much attention from doctors at all and pretty much left to die from diseases that could be treated or at least managed here in the US.

He is 74 years old, relatively healthy and active. Yet, I'd like for him to undergo tests and screenings that are appropriate for his age to get an accurate picture of his health. Since he is just visiting, he is not eligible for Medicare.

***The question is:***

1) What would be the best way to do this diagnostics for him? (logistically)

2) What is the best way to pay for it? Paying out of pocket and buying a private insurance are on the table.

Comment: Question #1 "What would be the best way to do this diagnostics for him? (logistically)" is **definite** of-topic.  As for #2, you two will have to determine which tests and screenings you want to perform, how much they cost, etc.  Note also that non-Medicare health insurance for old people is likely to be **expensive**, and I doubt you could even get it for someone here on a travel visa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Get liquid funds ready in advance, be prepared to put down sizeable cash deposits for services you can't or don't want to purchase outright, and try to negotiate discounts for paying bills immediately and in cash.

I spent quite a few years working in the financial services office of a large hospital, and have personal experience dealing with this sort of situation from the health care provider's point of view. That's the view that matters, because if you can't satisfy a provider's concerns they can easily refuse to provide the services you're describing.

There is an upside and a downside to the situation you describe, and they are complements of one another. The basic elements are:

- You want your father to receive a *known* set of specific medical
  procedures while in the U.S.
- Your father is in a relatively high-risk age category regarding
  medical expenditures
- Your father does not currently have any sort of insurance to cover
  medical expenses
- Your father resides, and presumably most or all of his assets are
  located in, a country other than the U.S.

First I'll list the downsides of that setup:

- This situation isn't how insurance is really supposed to work. You
  100% intend for your father to incur the medical expenses for the
  tests you have in mind while he's here. In insurance terms, the cost
  risk is 1-- there is *no benefit of any kind* to an insurer offering
  coverage for those services, since the expenses *will* happen, unless the insurer charges you more than those services would cost without the coverage. In which case you may as well skip the insurance altogether.
- Any insurance your father might be able to access will almost
  certainly include coverage for far more than routine tests, and so
  will be priced according to a more complete array of health risks your
  father experiences. That means it will likely be *expensive*,
  addressing the possible need for services well beyond screenings.
- As someone who will only be in the U.S. for a fairly brief time, and
  will then return to another country, efforts to collect outstanding
  bills will become more time consuming and expensive. Health care
  providers may be more reluctant to offer any sort of financing, and
  the terms that they offer may not be very generous.
- There is no way to guarantee, or even plausibly suggest, that the
  medical expenses your father incurs will be limited to these tests
  alone. For example, if a test reveals an urgent need for medical
  services (such as surgery) it might not be realistic to claim that
  you and your father would not *demand* those services. In some cases
  the health care provider may be legally obligated to provide those
  services immediately.
- There are few, if any, options a health care provider has to deal
  with an outstanding balance. Programs like Medicaid may be available,
  to some degree, depending on the state you live in (and I wouldn't
  count on it-- those sorts of special permissions are rare and their
  criteria narrow). It is likely that, in the event of non-payment, the
  provider would have to write off the balances as a loss or use part
  of an uncompensated care fund. In either of those cases the provider
  will have a limited amount of resources to defray those sorts of
  bills, and may be unwilling or unable to absorb such a loss. In this scenario that would play out as reluctance or refusal to extend any sort of financing at all.

The sum of all of that is that you're not really in the market for insurance (you're not trying to hedge against uncertain risks) and health care providers have little incentive to carry financial risk on your father's behalf.

---

The upsides:

- Since insurance isn't quite on target for what you're looking for,
  and would likely be a poor fit for your situation even if you were
  looking for it, you can avoid one of the more complicated and
  frustrating elements of seeking medical care in the U.S. You don't
  have to worry about comparison shopping health insurance plans,
  dealing with provider networks, or anything like that. It's not a
  money saver for you, but it does remove a lot of complexity.
- Since you are looking at a set of relatively limited, discrete
  medical services, you can have a more straightforward conversation
  with health care providers about what you want and how you want to
  pay for it. There isn't much confusion about ICD-10 coding for a
  panel of blood tests or generic lab work.
- Since you are open to paying out-of-pocket for what are
  typically low-cost medical services, you have a good shot at
  obtaining those services by paying for them in cash, in advance, or
  putting down a sizeable deposit against the expected total bill.
- If you are willing and able to pay the bills in full and in cash for
  specific services, you can inquire about discounts off of the total
  charges. Many health care providers are willing to offer discounts on
  services in exchange for removing all uncertainty and administrative
  effort around collecting payments.

---

**You have a good chance of getting your father in to see a doctor or physician's assistant**, given the details outlined above, if you are willing to immediately pay or personally guarantee the bills. **You have virtually no chance of getting another party to shoulder any of the bills**, aside from a potential discount for paying upfront and in full.

dwizum made a great point in a comment about negotiating a discount: you don't have to work primarily from the charge master price (the "sticker price" that the provider charges by default). It's worth asking what a typical insurance plan would pay and then negotiating towards that number, rather than simply trying to get away from the charge master price. As always, the worst that will happen is they will decline to offer the discount you'd like, and with routine services that don't involve much uncertainty the provider may be more flexible than for other services.

So my advice is to schedule the appointments as far in advance of the visit as possible (to help with scheduling difficulties on the providers' ends), state your intention to pay the bills in cash at the time of service (or ask about a suitable cash deposit) while you are scheduling the appointments, and inquire about any discounts the provider may offer for a full cash payment at the time of service.

Be aware that these same conditions will hold should the tests suggest some additional care that might benefit your father, and that you will be in the position to pay these bills out of pocket too (you will be bearing that risk) *or* that you will not be able to pursue those services (without pursuing more convoluted ways of getting money, such as taking out a large personal loan yourself).

Different providers will have different procedures for this sort of thing, but be prepared to offer documentation of your finances overall to convince them that you are willing and able to pay the charges. You may also be asked to sign papers legally establishing you as the guarantor for your father's medical services in the U.S. with that provider.

In all cases, make an effort to record the name, title, and department of anyone you speak with that gives you information on these matters (it's really helpful to remember who said what and when, and bureaucracy tends to make that harder with hospitals and clinics), and where possible get relevant policies and assurances ***in writing***. I wouldn't make a huge deal out of that unless you really feel you have to, but uncertainty about the arrangements does not and will not favor you here.

Comment: How much of a cash discount can one expect?  (I just got a 44% discount through my insurance company.)

Comment: @RonJohn It's impossible to estimate well in the general case. It's largely a function of the charge master price (which you'll never see), the cost of interacting with insurers for payment, typical costs of collection efforts, "fluff" on the charge master price, the provider's overall financial situation, executive fiat, and other hard-to-assess factors. I can't reveal numbers from experience in my former job, but anecdotally for office visits I've heard of discounts ranging from 0% to ~70%. There is no downside to asking, but I would be prepared for the worst case of no discount at all.

Comment: This is a great answer. I would just add, don't negotiate just on the "cash price." Providers are tuned to getting paid by insurance companies, which usually contract to pay flat rates for services based on a percentage of [CMS](https://www.cms.gov/apps/physician-fee-schedule/search/search-criteria.aspx) or other publicly-available fee schedules. You can always ask, *what would a typical insurer pay for this?* or, *what would medicare pay for this?* and then bargain to that number. A basic new patient office visit (99201) usually pays around $50 but some providers will bill it at $200 or more.

Comment: @dwizum That's a great point, especially for routine services. I've edited that suggestion into my answer.